# Crtical section not working in OpenMP program

Tags: openmp, critical-section

Q. Fill an array of size 100 with 1. Find sum of the array.

So i ran the below program on linux compiled with the flag -fopenmp and the answer i am getting is Sum : 400 (As 4 cores ) but it should be 100 as its in critical section
Note: Dont mind intialiazing of 1 , I was told to do this for this question

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <omp.h>



int main()

{

    int size=100;

    int a[size];

    double sum=0.0;

    

    for (int i =0;i<size/4;i++)

        a[i]=1;

        

    for (int i =size/4;i<size/2;i++)

        a[i]=1;

        

    for (int i =size/2;i<3*size/4;i++)

        a[i]=1;

        

    for (int i =3*size/4;i<size;i++)

        a[i]=1;

    

    

    #pragma omp parallel shared(sum)

    {

        for(int i =0;i<size;i++){

    #pragma omp critical

         {

                sum+=a[i];

         }

        }

    }

    

    printf("Sum : %f",sum);

    

    

    

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your big mistake is using `omp parallel` without `for`: now every thread executes the whole for loop (because `omp parallel` only creates the threads) and your result is 4x too large. You need to use: `omp parallel for`, which contains the `omp for` "worksharing" construct.

Conceptual mistake: critical sections are really bad for performance in simple cases like this. You will get the right result, but no speedup. Use a `reduction` clause on your `parallel for`. Try to avoid `critical` and `atomic` as much as possible.

Btw, why all the blank lines? That just makes it harder for us to read.

Comment: Sorry for the blank lines , I was debugging so much editing and deleting stuff , blank lines stayed